# Request doesn't use saved cookies in PersistentCookieStore

Tags: java, android, http, cookies

I fixed the crash and error in my app when I declared a cookie store, but it doesn't save the cookies or something went wrong at an other position.

At first I call these 2 lines:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore;
```

And then I have a POST:

```
public void postRequestLogin(String url, RequestParams params) {
    myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
    client.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
            System.out.println(response);

            if(response.contains("Login successful!")) {
                TextView lblStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblStatus);
                lblStatus.setText("Login successful!");
                getRequest("url");
            } else {
                TextView lblStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblStatus);
                lblStatus.setText("Login failed!");
                TextView source = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response_request);
                source.setText(response);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Then it should save the Logincookies and use it for the GET Request:

```
public void getRequest(String url) {
    myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
            System.out.println(response);
            TextView responseview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response_request);
            responseview.setText(response);
        }
    });
}
```

But it doesn't use the cookies. When I do the GET Request I'm already logged out.

Edit: I forgot to say that I use a lib from this tutorial: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: It's important to make your title specific, because it makes it more likely that people who know how to help will see your question. You don't need to use words like "Android" or "Java" because the question already has tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set the cookie store after the request has already completed (in the `onSuccess` method). Try setting it before you make that request:

```
myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
client.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

You're also creating a new cookie store on every request. What happens if you do more than one request? It will create a new cookie store and use it (and the new cookie store won't have your cookies). Try moving this part of the code to your constructor:

```
myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
```

Then remove it from the other functions.

Comment: @Phil Also, I was just looking at your code again, and you're creating a new cookie store on every request. You should only call `new PersistentCookieStore()` and `setCookieStore` once (probably in the constructor).

Comment: Ok, I did it now just in the constructor, works fine, thanks again