# How save cookie between request in asyncHttpClient?

Tags: java, httprequest, asynchttpclient

I send two request and I want do second request with cookie (cookie from response from first request).

How it work now:

```
Future<Response> f = asyncHttpClient
    .prepareGet(URL_1)
    .execute();
Response r = f.get();

/* I want code without saving and restoring cookie */
List<Cookie> cookies = r.getCookies();
AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder b = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(URL_2)
for (Cookie c : cookies) {
  b.addCookie(c);
}

f = b.execute();
r = f.get();
```

I want remove complex code, how can I do it

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Java8` already, then [ComparableFuture](http://allegrotech.io/async-rest.html) may help you with requests sequential run. Otherwise, you can find useful `RxJava` third-party (link to `RxJava` is in the article summary).

Comment: The problem is not the amount of code, problem in logic.
I want to asynchttpClient keep cookies if they come in response.

Comment: ah, ok. then you can check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668186/request-doesnt-used-saved-cookies-in-persistentcookiestore.